# Solve equation 2^x in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a number wich is a sum of 2^x

For example 104 = 2^3+2^5+2^6

I want to have a simple function that

return true if a number can be a sum of 2^x

And if x may be a second number.

Example myfunc (3,104) = true

(5,104) = true

But myfunc (3,2) = false

Because we cant find a number 2^3 + nb = 2

Thank you and sorry for my english

Comment: you forgot to post your code & what issue youre encountering

Comment: 2^0 == 1 so all numbers are a sum of 2^x, otherwise binary numbers wouldn't work.

Comment: Interesting how the two answers transpose the definitions of your/you're.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All integer numbers and floating numbers that can be represented by a computer can be represented as the sum of powers of two.

If you mean that `2^i` occurs in the sum, you're function should simply check the bitwise mask:

```
public static boolean myfunc (int i, int n) {
    return ((0x01<<i)&n != 0x00);
}
```

The function works as follows:

```
0x01<<i
```

returns `2^i`, then you use the `&` operator: bitwise AND. If this means that `2^i` is returned, if and only if `2^i` is part of the sum. Thus by checking if the result is not zero, you determine this.

Comment: is there a reason you used hex over decimal?

Comment: @LoganMurphy: hex is in many cases used when one works with bitwise operations, quite common. But you're right it is of course arbitrary. And furthermore hex numbers have some nice interesting properties. The decimal system was probably one of the worst decisions men have made...

Comment: thank you for sharing some facts and opinions...i dont think the rest of the world is ready to start counting with letters yet though lol ;)

Comment: @LoganMurphy: sure, but the big problem with the decimal number system is that it has only `2` dividers: `2` and `5`. In case we would use `12` as radix, `1/3` would be `0.4` which is more convenient.

Comment: I think it is safe to say that base 10 provides more accurate tracking of fractional numbers at least...and that certain radices are better in certain situations

Comment: Thank you it's what i'm looking for, for people who asking why i want to use this : i have two table A and B in B we can have 1000 item of A, to avoid to have 1000 row joining idA,idB i have a column in B containing 2^idA1 + 2^idA2 + 2^idA3 + 2^idA4 , and to know if idA=17 is in the sum 541 i use the myfunc of CommuSoft ;)   may be there is a better solution. thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Every non-negative integer can be written as a series of `2^x`, for integral `x`.

What your doing is essentially decomposing the number into binary.